# Run Time Error: External table is not in the expected format

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, ado

I am trying to pull data from a ***Shared Drive*** without opening the file.
I used *ADO* so I can manipulate the resulting table easily since I just need specific fields.
Rather than doing the filter and copy routine, *ADO* is preferable since I can use *sql query* to get what I want.

The line: `rec.Open sqlStr, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly`

throws the error

> Run-time error ...:
>   External table is not in the expected format.

[image]

The file is in *.xls* format and it is included in the *Trust Center* default setting of blocked files (files that will be opened in Protected View).

Out of curiosity, I temporarily disabled the file blocking but the same error occurred.

***When I open the file and run the code, it retrieves the data.***

How can I make this work without opening the file?

**Code I use:**

```
Sub stancial()
    Dim sPath As String, fName As String

    sPath = "P:\Folder\": fName = "Report.xls"

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection: Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset: Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim DataSource As String
    DataSource = sPath & fName

    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & DataSource & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

    Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog: Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
    Set cat.ActiveConnection = con

    Dim shName As String
    shName = Replace(cat.Tables(0).Name, "'", "")

    Dim sqlStr As String
    sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [" & shName & "];"

    rec.Open sqlStr, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rec

    rec.Close
    con.Close
    Set cat = Nothing
    Set rec = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit1:**

I also tried this:

```
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & DataSource & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
```

and also this:

```
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & DataSource & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
```

It still gives the error. I think is has something to do with opening the *Recordset* rather than the *Connection*.

Comment: `"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""`in your connection string refers to Excel 2007 and higher in xlsx XML format. Try `"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES""` for xls files.

Comment: @AxelRichter Oh, forgot to mention, I've tried that. Same Error. Also, I think there's no problem in setting the connection but opening the *Recordset*.

Comment: Hm, but the error says just this: not the expected format. What format is the file really? Really Excel 97-2003 xls? How it was created?

Comment: @AxelRichter Yep, that is the format. I is a machine generated file which are inspection results. I was working on a template that will summarize machine output. So I need to get certain data fields from the machine generated file saved in a shared drive. I can open these files manually and as I've mentioned, if the file is open, the code executes without error.

Comment: I suspect the machine that is generating this does something wrong. Try open the file in Excel, save it with different filename in Excel 97-2003 xls format. Put it on the shared drive and then try with this file. If it works then, my suspect was correct. Btw.: That it works with open files has not really something to say. If you have open a test.csv file in Excel, then you can access even this with ADO and the Excel-driver.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yeah, you are correct. I did save a copy (.xls) of it and it works fine. Are there restrictions on what file it can read? As I see it, it is *.xls* format. And when I open it, it is ok. How come I can't read it through *ADO*. Any suggestion? I really need to get data without opening it.

Comment: The restriction are: It has to be a XLS file in correct format. So how i had suspected, the machine that is generating this file does something wrong. What machine (software) is this?

Comment: @AxelRichter Post your comment into an answer and I will accept it. Your comments are sufficient enough to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a machine generated XLS-File, I suspect the machine, that is generating this, does something wrong. Try open the file in Excel, save it with different filename in Excel 97-2003 xls format. Put it on the shared drive and then try with this file. If it works then, my suspect was correct.

Btw.: That it works with open files has not really something to say. If you have open a test.csv file in Excel, then you can access even this with ADO and the Excel-driver.

You can check this, if you try:

```
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & "C:\path\test.csv" & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
```

this will fail, if test.csv is not open in Excel. Now open test.csv in Excel and try again. Now it will succeed.

That in your case it fails so late, suggests that the error is not large enough to prevent even the connection.

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone currently having this problem what seems like randomly, I've found it may still have to do with your connection string not including `IMEX=1`.

Example: `con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"`

> To always use IMEX=1 is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data columns. Consider the scenario that one Excel file might work fine cause that file's data causes the driver to guess one data type while another file, containing other data, causes the driver to guess another data type. This can cause your app to crash.

A helpful source for connection strings can be found at: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the error when using adodb to read from a specific .xlsx file. I changed the format to .xls and after that the error subsided. All good, but after a while, on another computer, the problem came up again, this time when trying to read another file.
The problem I found is that the first row which contained the column headers had vertical and horizontal central alignment. After restoring the alignments to default, the error stopped.